# How to request different domain with Ajax in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, cross-domain

I need to make a request to a different domain with Ajax in jQuery!

Should I use `iframe`?

Edited:

On facebook.com working chat, with few different domain name?

GET http:// www.facebook.com/ajax/presence/reconnect.php?__a=1&reason=6&iframe_loaded=false&post_form_id=23be2df75b74a0bcb61358814c56ba4f 200 OK

GET http://0.50.channel.facebook.com/x/2562941315/4271808869/true/p_1529934952=2 200 OK

I want something like...

Answer (score 6):

You can not because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You have a few options.

#### [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)

You make a request with a `script` element, and pass it a callback to one of your functions to handle the data.

#### [Server side proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

Basically, you create a wrapper on the server side. You can use cURL or equivalent. Request the data with your server and then serve it from under the same domain.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Here is a little more info on the why not that I thought others may find useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Consider using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) instead, which uses `<script>` tags to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and JSONP